# OctoberCMS blog post image size into the Ace Editor

Tags: image, ace-editor, octobercms

I have a question related to image size and customization into the blog post.
For example, I have that code for image integration:

```
![9_main.jpg](http://hql-blog.loc/storage/app/uploads/public/5a9/a2b/0db/5a9a2b0db7aec777751196.jpg)
```

How can I change its width or height, maybe border and etc.
Where can I find some format documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, not sure you can do that directly but, hey do you know you can use direct HTML in mark down.

you can use `media` to select image then it will output like this as you showed

```
![9_main.jpg](http://hql-blog.loc/...big_path.../5a9a2b0db7aec777751196.jpg)
```

now you can use this path and replace this with

```
<img src="http://hql-blog.loc/...big_path.../5a9a2b0db7aec777751196.jpg" 
    alt="9_main.jpg" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

now you can add whatever style you want